# I cannot find the default.aspx page in the cqwp

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am trying to extract and display the content editor web part within the site default page on another page.  When using the cqwp, I cannot find the default page at all.
Thank you for your help

More details:
My site main screen with address (...../default.aspx) has multiple sections and webparts.  I want to display one of the webpart (Content Editor) in another web site so that I dont have to make edit in both places if the content changes.
I have published this page and have made it the site HOME page, but cannot find this page in the query.

Answer (score 1):

When the CQWP is configured well, then most of the time this is because pages aren't published as a major version. To do so: Check in the page as a major version, then accept the changes. (When using approval mechanism)

If this doesn't help you, I suppose you have to provide us more detailed information about: What you want to do and how you configured the necessities.